# Office 2013 doesn't zoom in real time?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2010, zoom, microsoft-office-2013

In Office 2010, I was holding `Control` button while scrolling and the document was **zooming in real-time**.

Now, in Office 2013, it instead shows "Text Zoom: N%" (N is the zoom value, obviously...), and then immediately zooms in/out - it doesn't zoom while I scroll.

How to get back to real-time zooming in Office 2013 as in 2010 ?

Comment: Hm, I'm running Word 2013 on Windows 7 Enterprise x64 through Terminal Services, and it's live-zooming for me. Perhaps you have some graphic setting such as "Disable hardware acceleration" or something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was probably done as part of Microsoft's initiative to make their applications less power-hungry and more tablet-friendly, and is unlikely to be able to be changed without a third-party add in that overrides the functionality, if it's possible.  I don't know of any such add-ins.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Office 2016, so it might be slightly different than 2013. The scroll-zoom works normally in Word, but *only* if opened independently. In Outlook messages, or in Word when opened from an Outlook attachment, scroll-zoom has the terrible "Text Zoom" message.

If I find a real solution I will update here, but it appears this isn't an option you can configure in Office.